# Freeing memory space when deleting a node in a circular LinkedList without declaring a new pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list, dynamic-programming, singly-linked-list

I've come across a problem in dynamic programming in which we are asked to delete nodes of a circular LinkedList, in the following manner.
Delete the first node then skip one and delete the next, then skip two and delete the next, then skip three and delete the next and it continues until we are left with only one node, and that one node is our answer.
For example, if we have 5 nodes, then the nodes will be deleted in the following order – 1 3
2 5 4, and the last node would be 4.
Similarly, if we have 4 nodes, then the nodes will be deleted in the following order – 1 3 4
2, and the last node would be 2.

[This is a screenshot of the part of the code that requires improvement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUt3t.png)

using this code in c++, I've been successful in solving the problem but I want to free the memory using `delete` command as I delink a node. **Can anyone please help me to solve this problem by improving this code (while using minimal memory)?
The node can be deleted by declaring another pointer, but that would only increase the memory usage, which I don't want at the moment.**
*The entire code is given below*

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class linked {
public:
    int x;
    linked* next;

    //methods
    linked(int p); //constructor
    static void insert(linked*& head, int p);//method to insert new node
    static int print(linked* head);//method to print the result


    static void del(linked*head, int size) {//method to delete all the undesired nodes
        linked* temp = head;
        while (temp->next != head) {//traversing until we find the node just behind the node we want to del
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        for(int i=1;i < size;i++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {//del nodes with increment
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = temp->next->next; //delinking the  
        }   
    }
 };



int main() {

    int no_of_nodes;
    cout << "enter the number of nodes you want to have" << endl;
    cin >> no_of_nodes;
    linked* head = new linked(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_nodes; i++) {
        linked::insert(head, i);//for inserting nodes, as desired by the user
    }
    
    linked::del(head, no_of_nodes);
    cout<< linked::print(head);

}




linked::linked(int p) {
    x = p;
    next = NULL;
}




void linked::insert(linked*& head, int p) {
    linked* temp = head;
    linked* n = new linked(p);//for the new node
    if (p == 1) {
        head->next = head;
        return;
    }
    while (temp->next != head) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = n;
    n->next = head;
}




int linked::print(linked* head) {
    linked* temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {//this can go longer(or shorter), i limited it to 25 only, just to ensure that it is a circular linked list

        temp = temp->next;

        if (temp == temp->next) {
            return temp->x;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

*P.S. The problem was taken from ICPC Asia Topi 2022, link:* (https://giki.edu.pk/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/ICPC_Day_2.pdf)

Comment: In the real world it is no problem to use another pointer. I guess this is a homework exercise?

Comment: Is there any information in the picture that you don't already show in the code block in the question?

Comment: "_The node can be deleted by declaring another pointer, but that would only increase the memory usage, which I don't want at the moment._": What does that mean? What pointer would increase memory usage? I don't understand what exactly the problem is. Just `delete` the node in `del` when you delink it.

Comment: Also, in the real world you would simply use `std::list<int>` which has a `erase` member to remove elements.

Comment: @AbdullahHabib I have not understood. Do you need to delete all nodes or all nodes except one?

Comment: @AbdullahHabib And the function insert does not make a sense. What does this if statement     if (p == 1) {
        head->next = head;
        return;
    }  mean?!

Comment: @AbdullahHabib And why do member functions of the class declared as static? I am sure you are not ready to ask the question. At first you need to rewrite the class.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you for replying to my post. yes, I want to delete all nodes except for one, insert function was designed in a way that the first node is declared as head and it would not need another pointer to point towards itself.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I used static, because i dont want to over burden my memory by declaring new methods for each object(or each node), these methods would work for every node, while being initialize once, hence saving the memory

Comment: @user253751 thank you for replying, no this is not a homework assignment, as mentioned in the post, this is a problem from a dynamic programming competition last year.

Comment: okay so it's still a competition where they told you to use as few variables as possible?

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for replying, no the snap is there just to emphasize the part of the code that needs improvement

Comment: @user253751 its more of like we have to make sure that we use memory and time efficiently to secure more marks

Comment: @AbdullahHabib Ok, in that case, the picture doesn't help. I suggest that you remove it and add extra comments in the code in the question if you want to emphasize something.

Comment: The last remaining node seems to follow this pattern: https://oeis.org/A007495 If you implement this formula, you can find the node that "survives" in O(n) time instead of O(n^2)

Comment: @user17732522 it tried using ```delete``` but it simply wont work without delcaring another pointer

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what will increase memory use of the program. Non-static member functions do not use any more memory than static ones. Declaring single extra local pointer variables in a function doesn't predictably increase memory use of that function. You have no idea how the compiler will optimize the function. Most likely that pointer is just going to be kept in a register and not use any space at all. Even if it used stack space, it would not be measurable from the outside. And the pointer must be kept in a register anyway due to the surrounding code.

Comment: All in all, the restrictions you are imposing on yourself make no sense. Who told you that these things would matter for memory usage?

Comment: @Artyer thanks for trying to help me out, but it does not follow this sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems neither professional programmer are going to help you.:)

So we, beginners, should help each other.:)

You should declare a class of the circular singly-linked list with non-static member functions.

As for the task to remove all elements from the circular singly-linked list except one using the described algorithm then I can suggest the following approach.

At first within the function remove the cycling. This will make easy to remove elements from the circular singly-linked list.
After all elements except one will be removed then restore the cycling.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

class CircularList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr;

public:
    CircularList() = default;
    CircularList( const CircularList & ) = delete;
    CircularList &operator =( const CircularList & ) = delete;
    ~CircularList()
    {
        clear();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        if (head)
        {
            Node *current = head;
            do
            {
                delete std::exchange( current, current->next );
            } while (current != head);

            head = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void insert( int data )
    {
        Node *new_node = new Node{ data };

        if (not head)
        {
            new_node->next = new_node;
            head = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *current = head;
            while (current->next != head) current = current->next;
            new_node->next = head;
            current->next = new_node;
        }
    }

    const int & top() const
    {
        if (not head)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range( "Error. The list is empty." );
        }

        return head->data;
    }

    void remove_except_one()
    {
        if (head)
        {
            Node *last = head;

            while (last->next != head) last = last->next;
            last->next = nullptr;

            Node **current = &head;

            for (size_t n = 0; head->next != nullptr; ++n)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i != n; i++)
                {
                    current = &( *current )->next;
                    if (*current == NULL) current = &head;
                }

                Node *tmp = *current;

                //  The statement below is uncommented for the debug pyrpose.
                std::cout << ( *current )->data << '\n';

                *current = ( *current )->next;
                if (*current == nullptr) current = &head;
                delete tmp;
            }

            head->next = head;
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, const CircularList &list )
    {
        if (list.head)
        {
            const Node *current = list.head;
            do
            {
                os << current->data << " -> ";
                current = current->next;
            } while (current != list.head);
        }

        return os << "null";
    }
};

int main()
{
    CircularList list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        list.insert( i + 1 );
    }

    std::cout << "The list: ";
    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.remove_except_one();

    std::cout << "The list: ";
    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.clear();

    std::cout << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        list.insert( i + 1 );
    }

    std::cout << "The list: ";
    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.remove_except_one();

    std::cout << "The list: ";
    std::cout << list << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
The list: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
1
3
2
5
The list: 4 -> null

The list: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
1
3
4
The list: 2 -> null
```

Within the function `remove_except_one` this statement

```
std::cout << ( *current )->data << '\n';
```

is present for the debug purpose only. You may remove or comment it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code:

**1) empty list should be nullptr**

In main:

```
linked* head = new linked(1);
```

should be

```
linked* head = nullptr;
```

You start with an empty list. You do not know what data you will insert first and you assume the first value inserted will be 1. With this change you also have to change your insert:

```
if (p == 1) {
```

has to check

```
if (head == nullptr) {
```

**2) replace head with tail**

In a circular single linked list you always need the previous node to delete a node or to insert at the head. That means you have to traverse the whole list when given the head to find the previous. This is rather slow, so store the tail of the list instead. Then the head is tail->next and you can delete the head or insert at the head directly.

**3) del breaks head**

```
static void del(linked*head, int size) {
```

If this deletes the first node in the list then the head the caller passed in  becomes a dangling pointer. There is no way to update the pointer the caller holds for the list. Just like with insert you need to pass in a reference:

```
static void del(linked*&head, int size) {
```

---

Now for your problem of how to delete the node without extra memory:

You can't. You always need extra memory to temporarily store the node to be deleted while you fix up the links in the list and then delete it. You already needed that extra memory to find the tail of the list and you called it `temp`.

```
static void del(linked*&tail) {
    if (tail == nullptr) return; // no list, nothing to delete
    for (std::size_t skip = 0; tail->next != tail; ++skip) { // keep going till only one node is left
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < skip; ++i) tail = tail->next; // skip nodes
        // delete node
        linked* temp = tail->next;
        tail->next = tail->next->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```